# How to style a outgoing email from contact form with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, email, contacts

I am trying to a style the outgoing email
for a contact form, but Im new to php Ive tried inline styles but this doesn
    't work. I understand that the css must go under **'
$emailbody
    '***. I have copied all of the code in so there isn't anything missing, hope this helps.

---

```
//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//validate form data

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}

//validate message is not empty
if(empty($message)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
}
//validate message is greater than 20 charcters
elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
}

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){

    /*ini_set("SMTP","mail.domain.com"); //mail.yoursite.com should be your local smtp
    ini_set("smtp_port","25"); //25 should be your smtp port
    ini_set("sendmail_from","example@email.com"); //info@yoursite.com should be your site email*/


    ini_set("sendmail_from","example@email.com");
    ini_set("SMTP","mail.btconnect.com"); //mail.yoursite.com should be your local smtp
    ini_set("smtp_port","25"); //25 should be your smtp port

    $headers = "From: enquiry@email.co.uk" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    $emailbody = "

                <html>
                 <body>
                 <head></head>
                  <h1><p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries from your website.</p></h1>
                  <h2><p>Name / Company:</h2><strong> {$name} </p></strong> 
                  <h2><p>Email Address:</h2>  <strong>{$email}</strong> </p>
                  <h2><p>Telephone:</h2>  <strong>{$telephone} </strong></p>
                  <h2><p>Enquiry: </h2><strong> {$enquiry} <strong></p>
                  <h2><p>Message: </h2><strong> {$message} <strong></p>
                  <h3><p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p></h3>
                 </body>
                </html>
                  ";


            mail("example@email.com","Estates & Law Website Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);







}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'telephone' => $telephone,
        'enquiry' => $enquiry,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);


//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ? It seems you are on the good way.

Comment: I don't think you'd need html, body, or head. Just wrap it in a div and style that accordingly?

Comment: Try adding `$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Place that ^^^ above `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html...`

Comment: ive tried warping it in a div and inline styling it because the stylesheet isnt linked to that page but it doesn't work. I want to wrap it so i can change the background and that.

Comment: *"because the stylesheet isnt linked to that page"* - Gmail etc. will scrap that. You MUST use inline styling.

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking. adding the content-type...

Comment: @jonathanl5660 Consult my answer/example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"but Im new to php Ive tried inline styles but this doesn 't work."*

*"ive tried warping it in a div and inline styling it because the stylesheet isnt linked to that page but it doesn't work. I want to wrap it so i can change the background and that."*

Since you haven't provided any examples of what "did not" work, am providing you with the following example.

Do keep in mind that email clients such as Gmail etc., will ignore linked stylesheets or if set inside `<style></style>` tags, so you **MUST** use inline styling.

You can take it from here and modify to suit, while following the same syntax.

```
$emailbody = "

            <html>
             <body LINK=\"#ff8080\" VLINK=\"#ff0000\" ALINK=\"a05050\" STYLE=\"background: #000000; color: #80c0c0\">
             <head></head>
              <h1><p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries from your website.</p></h1>
              <h2><p>Name / Company:</h2><strong> {$name} </p></strong> 
              <h2><p>Email Address:</h2>  <strong>{$email}</strong> </p>
              <h2><p>Telephone:</h2>  <strong>{$telephone} </strong></p>
              <h2><p>Enquiry: </h2><strong> {$enquiry} <strong></p>
              <h2><p>Message: </h2><strong> {$message} <strong></p>
              <h3><p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p></h3>


<div><div STYLE=\"font-weight: bold; margin-left: 30px\">
<span STYLE=\"font-size: x-large; color: #ffffff\">M</span>y wonderful poetry</div> is available if you are REALLY bored. Why not give it a spin?</div> 


 </body>
</html>
  ";
```

---

You'll need to escape double quotes `"` such as `\"` or use single quotes when inside `echo`.

I.e.:

```
<div STYLE=\"font-weight: bold; margin-left: 30px\">
```

or

```
<div STYLE='font-weight: bold; margin-left: 30px'>
```

Comment: this is great thanks did not know i needed the **/** thats what was wrong with the code I should have provide examples of what i tried sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Emails client support only inline style attribute for CSS such as :

```
 <div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Some text</div>
```

It won't work if you write your css in the `<head>`, write all your styles inside the HTML tags

Also refer to this list to see which css properties are compatible with the major mail clients :
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score -1):

In your email body-

- `<head>` is inside body. standard is head must start and end before `<body>` tag.
- Inside `<head>` tag, include a `<style>` tag and place your css codes inside `<style>`
- Or else, try inline css within html body. Such as `<p height=\"auto\"></p>` . And of course, remember to put `"\"` to escape.